# Implement Scroll bar in highcharts

Tags: highcharts, scrollbar

Can anyone please tell me is there any way to include scroll bar in highcharts without using highstock.js 
( use only highcharts.js) ?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the scrollbar is available only in the highstock.js.